# Snap.SVG attaching SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to insert an SVG using snap.svg, to a page and then have it rotate and expand slightly. I'm using brackets at the moment as some local live preview thing, and the problem I'm having is twofold; I managed to get it in place about half an hour ago and then broke it somehow and now I don't know how to get it back, and the syntax for snap.svg is condensed enough to make it kind of iffy to read, and the documentation isn't very good, so I'm unable to work out how exactly I do what I want to do. I gave search a go, but the callback method I found doesn't seem to be working. Can anybody help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>


    <body>
    <script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var paper = Snap(500,500),
        Snap.load('ringing-phone.svg', function (phone) {
        phone.selectAll("path[fill='#ff0000']").attr({fill: "#00ff00"});
        var g = phone.select("g");
    });
        </script>



    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: Please (a) test the code directly in the browser as well as in Brackets live preview mode; (b) report whether you're getting any errors in your browser console (in case its a file load issue); and (c) more clearly explain what you're trying to achieve and what is happening instead.  You're not currently doing anything with the external SVG file -- should you be appending it to something?

Comment: Oop, now I feel dumb. So, in the javascript dev console, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." Assuming the "." on line 10, "Snap.load('ringing-phone.svg', function (phone)", both of the periods seem fine to me there, one denotes file format, the other a method declaration. Sorry about this, my background is more in the Java/C++ side of things, this is my first foray into web design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a naughty comma after the var paper line, it should be a semicolon, as you aren't defining a variable on the next line.

```
var paper = Snap(500,500); //<-- this semicolon
Snap.load('ringing-phone.svg', ....
```

Comment: We've all been there :)

Comment: Also, I was wanting to transform the shape on mouse click with a 45 degree rotation and a slight scaling operation. I've seen your name pop up fairly often in snap related threads, I was wondering if you could point me the right way? The documentation is a bit tricky for me personally. I feel like I've jumped into the deep end a bit.

Comment: Hmm I have a post somewhere and can't find it! It would look something like phone.transform('t10,10r45s1.5'). Which would translate 10,10 then rotate 45 around the center (you can do r45,100,100 to rotate around a point if needed if its not centered), and s1.5 to scale (again this will scale around center, but you can do s1,2,100,100 to scale x,y around a different point). You can add more, just remember the order of transformations in svg can be important, as you are changing coordinate systems for future transforms.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do it. One last thing, I need to change out the SVG now, but when I change out the SVG for literally any other SVG, the debugger presents the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouseover' of null", which I can't seem to really work out exactly where or why that's happening.

Comment: No idea, I think you would need to post a testing example on a jsfiddle to have a chance of seeing. Make sure it can see the file you are trying to load, and preferably its on the same server (otherwise you may get errors). Check the console log for errors and post another question if still struggling.